# Android-Reduce APK size, separate APKs for different architectures

Tags: android, qt, apk, 64-bit

I am using native libraries in my Android application. Recently, I got a notification from Google to conform to the new requirement asking to provide support for 64bit architecture as well. My current architecture is armeabi-v7a and I have built my libraries for arm64-v8a and packaged them inside my APK under "libs" folder. Google Play is accepting my APK but packaging everything into one APK has almost doubled the size of my APK. I was just wondering if I build separate APKs for each architecture and publish them to Google Play will it work? I mean users with 64-bit devices get 64-bit APK and those with 32 bit get the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to use [app bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

You can build one APK per ABI, but this is a complicated maintenance which in particular requires diligence when assigning versionCode to each APK. This is known as [Multi APK](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) and is now discouraged in favour of the [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) which is a single artifact bundling all the files and leaves Play responsible for the generation of the final APKs to users, which it does in a clever way, serving to each device only the files it needs.